# Powertop reports wifi at 100% power use, even when it is switched off

Tags: wireless, power-management, powertop

[image: powertop session with wifi switched off]

I switched off the WiFi of my TigerLake laptop, and on top of that, also put it in Airplane mode, to be completely sure it is off.

Still, powertop keeps reporting a `100%` usage stat for Wifi.

Why is this?

OS: Ubuntu 22.10

CPU: i7-1165G7

System: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ZenBook UX325EA